# Which GeoPandas function checks if at least one point of a geometry is within another?

Tags: geometry, gis, geospatial, geopandas, shapely

I have a [GeoSeries](https://geopandas.org/en/stable/docs/reference/api/geopandas.GeoSeries.html#geopandas.GeoSeries) of linestrings, and a polygon. I aim to find those linestrings, which have at least one point within the polygon.

I know about [`geopandas.GeoSeries.within`](https://geopandas.org/en/stable/docs/reference/api/geopandas.GeoSeries.within.html). I could decompose my linestrings to a list of points, and then check if `each.within(polygon)`. If any point of a linestring are, I say the linestring has at least one point within the polygon.

**Is there a way of determining if parts of a linestring is within a polygon without decomposing the linestring to points?**

---

The functions I have looked at but do not work:

- [`GeoSeries.touches(other, align=True)`](https://geopandas.org/en/stable/docs/reference/api/geopandas.GeoSeries.touches.html)

Based on description, this is not what I need:

> An object is said to touch other if it has at least one point in
> common with other and its interior does not intersect with any part of
> the other. Overlapping features therefore do not touch.

- [`GeoSeries.overlaps(other, align=True)`](https://geopandas.org/en/stable/docs/reference/api/geopandas.GeoSeries.overlaps.html)

> Geometries overlaps if they have more than one but not all points in
> common, have the same dimension, and the intersection of the interiors
> of the geometries has the same dimension as the geometries themselves.

Does not work, and the reason I believe is that a line is 1 dimensional, a polygon is 2, so the *have the same dimension* condition is violated. I am unsure that this is the full reason, so here is a demonstration that this function does not work for the purpose described above:

```
import geopandas as gpd
from shapely.geometry import Polygon, LineString
```

Define a LineString and a Polygon:

```
l = LineString([(+0.25,0.5),(0.5,0.5),(1.5,0.5), (2.1, 0.5), (2,-1)])
l = gpd.GeoSeries([l])

p = Polygon([(0, 0), (2, 0), (2, 2), (0, 2), (0, 0)])
p = gpd.GeoSeries([p])
```

Plot them:

```
plt.plot([each[0] for each in list(l.iloc[0].coords)],
         [each[1] for each in list(l.iloc[0].coords)])

plt.plot(p.iloc[0].exterior.xy[0],p.iloc[0].exterior.xy[1])
```

[image]

Both `l.overlaps(p)` and `p.overlaps(l)` return

```
0    False
dtype: bool
```

which is not what's expected.

- [`geopandas.GeoSeries.intersects`](https://geopandas.org/en/stable/docs/reference/api/geopandas.GeoSeries.intersects.html)

Description:

> An object is said to intersect other if its boundary and interior
> intersects in any way with those of the other.

Some of the linestrings are entirely within my polygon. This function would return `False` and I would like to return `True` for those cases.

Comment: Intersects wouldn't work in your case?

Comment: Linestrings could be entirely within polygon, and I would like to return True for those cases, but intersects returns False.

Comment: But good point, I add it to the post.

Comment: Nope, if a LineString is fully within a polygon `intersects` returns `True`.

Comment: Oh ok. I was wrong then. Thanks.